# Build C++ Applications in a Amazon Linux 2 Docker Container with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio, rsync, amazon-linux-2

I followed the next URL and successfully built a simple C++ app on Ubuntu Docker container with Visual studio 2022.
[Build C++ Applications in a Linux Docker Container with Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/build-c-applications-in-a-linux-docker-container-with-visual-studio/)

Next, I tried using Amazon Linux 2, but the visual studio said it failed to start rsync on the remote host, so that I could not build a C++ app. I'm looking for the solutions to fix this problem.

These are my attempts.

The `Dockerfile` comes like this.

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

RUN yum -y update && yum install -y sudo passwd shadow-utils openssh-server wget tar g++ gdb ninja-build rsync zip make
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd && \
    echo PasswordAuthentication yes >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && \
    ssh-keygen -A
RUN useradd -m -d /home/master -s /bin/bash -G wheel master && echo master:pass | chpasswd

# CMake
RUN wget https://github.com/microsoft/CMake/releases/download/v3.19.4268486/cmake-3.19.4268486-MSVC_2-Linux-x64.sh && \
    chmod +x cmake-3.19.4268486-MSVC_2-Linux-x64.sh && \
    ./cmake-3.19.4268486-MSVC_2-Linux-x64.sh --skip-license --prefix=/usr

EXPOSE 22
```

`docker build` completed successfully.

```
docker build -t al2 -f Dockerfile.al2 .
```

Createing and Starting amazon linux 2 docker container completed successfully.

```
docker run -it -p 10022:22 --privileged al2 /sbin/init
```

I logged in to the docker container and started ssh service.

```
systemctl start sshd
systemctl enable sshd
```

I could login successfully with ssh from my local host.

```
ssh -p 10022 master@localhost
```

I could `rsync` correctly from my local wsl.

```
rsync -auzv test/ --rsh="ssh -p 10022" master@localhost:/home/master/test
```

Connection to the docker container from Visual Studio successed.

And then, I select `localhost` and started building C++ apps, but it stops because of the `rsync` issue.